# Select end row of table, copy and paste in another workbook

Tags: macos, vba

I have 2 workbooks.

Source Workbook
 - Select a cell in **column B,** last row of a table. e.g. B29 (But this would change as the table grows)

2nd Workbook 
- Paste that cell into **G14** of the 2nd workbook (This doesn't change)

Source Workbook
 - Select a cell in **column D**, same row - last row of table. e.g.. D29

2nd Workbook 
- Paste that cell into **D8** (This doesn't change)

This same process repeats 4 more times (**Columns E-H**) and all the pasting is done into **C3, F14, I14 and E14** respectively.

Comment: What's the name of the first and second workbook?

Comment: the first one is "Payment Request Builder" and the 2nd is "United"

Answer (score 1):

The following code will do what you need. Just make the changes mentioned in the comments.

```
Sub Copy2Workbook() 'You need to place this in your source workbook!
    Dim wbT As Workbook ' target workbook
    Set wbT = Workbooks("United")
    Dim shtT As Worksheet 'target worksheet
    Set shtT = wbT.Worksheets("Name of target sheet") ' change name to fit your case
    Dim shtS As Worksheet 'source worksheet
    Set shtS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of source sheet") ' change name to fit your case
    Dim lastRow As Long
    '*****************************************
    lastRow = shtS.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    shtT.Range("G14").Value = shtS.Range("B" & lastRow).Value
    'repeat the two lines of above while changing the references to your needs
End Sub
```

Comment: Sub Copy2Workbook() 'You need to place this in your source workbook!
    Dim wbT As Workbook ' target workbook
    Set wbT = Workbooks("United") 'I get an error here...Apologies, my understanding is very limited.

Comment: Is your target book "United" open?

Comment: Yes the target book is open.

Comment: What is the EXACT name of the target workbook (make sure there are no spaces in the name", including the extensions (.xls, .xslx).

Comment: United.xlsx...I'll be back on in a few hours. Thank you so far for your help.

Comment: Try `Set wbT = Workbooks("United.xlsx")`